# core Plot:Decrease distance between bar in bar graph ios

Tags: ios, core-plot

i am plotting 2 data set on bar graph and i want them to be like histogram ,so can anyone guide me to the solution asap.

i have 2 datasets(google and Apple)in 1 datasets.I am not getting any spaces between bars of 1 dataset but i am getting too much spacing between 2 datasets.

here is my code,

```
    -(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
    return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInWeek] count];
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if ((fieldEnum == CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip) && (index < [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInWeek] count]))
    {
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolAAPL])
        {
            NSLog(@"apple index:%@",[[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] weeklyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolAAPL] objectAtIndex:index]);
           return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] weeklyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolAAPL] objectAtIndex:index];
        }
        else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolGOOG])
        {
            NSLog(@"google index:%@",[[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] weeklyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolGOOG] objectAtIndex:index]);
            return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] weeklyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolGOOG] objectAtIndex:index];
        }
    }
    return [NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];



-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initPlot];
}

#pragma mark - Chart behavior
-(void)initPlot
{
    self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = YES;
    [self configureGraph];
    [self configurePlots];
    [self configureAxes];
    graphData=[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] weeklyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolAAPL];
    NSLog(@"google:%@",graphData);

}

-(void)configureGraph {
    // 1 - Create the graph
    CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];

    graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
    self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
    // 2 - Configure the graph
    [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme]];
    graph.paddingBottom = 30.0f;
    graph.paddingLeft  = 30.0f;
    graph.paddingTop    = -1.0f;
    graph.paddingRight  = -5.0f;
    CGFloat xMin = 0.0f;
    CGFloat xMax = [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInWeek] count];
    CGFloat yMin = 0.0f;
    CGFloat yMax = 800.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xMax)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMax)];

}

-(void)configurePlots
{
    // 1 - Set up the three plots
    self.aaplPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:105.0f/255.0f green:252.0f/255.0f blue:144.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0] horizontalBars:NO];
    self.aaplPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolAAPL;

    self.googPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:103.0f/255.0f green:103.0f/255.0f blue:103.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0] horizontalBars:NO];
    self.googPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolGOOG;

    // 2 - Set up line style
    CPTMutableLineStyle *barLineStyle = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init];
    barLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor lightGrayColor];
    barLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.5;

    // 3 - Add plots to graph
    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
    CGFloat barX = CPDBarInitialX;
    NSArray *plots =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.aaplPlot, self.googPlot, nil];
    for (CPTBarPlot *plot in plots)
    {
        plot.dataSource = self;
        plot.delegate = self;
        plot.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromDouble(CPDBarWidth);
        plot.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromDouble(barX);
        plot.lineStyle = barLineStyle;
        [graph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];
        barX += CPDBarWidth;
    }

}

-(void)configureAxes
{
    // 1 - Configure styles
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
    // 2 - Get the graph's axis set
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
    // 3 - Configure the x-axis
    axisSet.xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    axisSet.xAxis.title = @"Days of Week (Mon - Fri)";
    axisSet.xAxis.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.titleOffset = 10.0f;
    axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    // 4 - Configure the y-axis
    axisSet.yAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    axisSet.yAxis.title = @"Price";
    axisSet.yAxis.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.titleOffset = 5.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;

}

-(void)hideAnnotation:(CPTGraph *)graph
{
    if ((graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea) && (self.priceAnnotation)) {
        [graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea removeAnnotation:self.priceAnnotation];
        self.priceAnnotation = nil;
    }

}
```

Comment: What are `CPDBarInitialX` and `CPDBarWidth`?

Comment: CGFloat const CPDBarWidth = 0.15f;
CGFloat const CPDBarInitialX = 0.1f;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `CPDBarWidth = 0.15`, two bars take up only 30% of the space between successive bar locations. Increase the `barWidth` to reduce the space between neighboring bars.